# How to correctly remove shared with me item in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Ms Graph allows to receive list of items (files or folders) that were [shared with me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (logged account).

```
GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

But i didn't found API that allows to remove item from this list, i.e. stop sharing with me.
Web page of Shared files\folder contains command "Remove from shared list" that does required action. How can I do it by Ms Graph API?

Environment: OneDrive for Business.

**UPDATE**:
This question differs from [How to delete Shared Drive Item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67075942/987850). This question is about stoping sharing some file between two Business accounts while [How to delete Shared Drive Item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67075942/987850) is about hide shared item from shared list but preserving permission therefore access to shared resource should be preserved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Shared Drive Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075942/how-to-delete-shared-drive-item)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer

Comment: Because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075942/how-to-delete-shared-drive-item causes some confusion, I deleted it.

Comment: If you want to try [non-programmatically then try this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-sharing-onedrive-or-sharepoint-files-or-folders-or-change-permissions-0a36470f-d7fe-40a0-bd74-0ac6c1e13323).

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Graph API then there is no directly API available. The closest one would be to remove the permissions for the given shared drive item then you will see while the /sharedWithMe request will succeed with Files.Read or Files.ReadWrite permissions. Additionally, without one of the All permissions, shared items returned from this API will not be accessible.. In addition to this, then you can try the [following sample](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3018/remove-sharing-permissions-on-all-files-in-users-onedrive-for-business) & see if it helps.

Comment: @Dev Thanks, I'll try the sample. Yes I use "Files.ReadWrite.All" scope, so it should not be a problem. But i tried removing permission from remote item (not from shared item) and found that Microsoft Graph API returns "accessDenined" for Business account and works for Personal account. This behavior inconsistent makes me crazy. :(